# Node application failed to render page

Tags: node.js, express

My node application works fine until these days, it suddently failed to render page, here’s what happen:

1. Node application starts up at 06:00
2. All goes well until at 17:30, we found there’s no response when request to access the webpage, all the “render” related function failed, even the static page
3. We try to telnet the port, it’s connectable, and we try to call the api function (the “send” related function), there’s correct data response
4. We check the log (using log4js), found that the log was stop logging at around 13:15
5. We check the CPU usage, just 2%
6. We check the process memory, it’s around 1.4G memory was in used, so far so good, and the entire pc still has 4G memory available
7. Checked the Windows event log, there’s no related event, and also there’s no I/O error event
8. We restart the node application, everything resume back to normal, the webpage goes back

And this is my setting.js api function which works fine during webpage not available

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
var lang = req.query.lang || req.session.userOptions.lang || 'en-US'
res.send({
    data: {
        lang: lang
    }
})
```

})

And this is the user.js which failed to render page

```
router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
res.render(__views_path + 'user/login', {
    layout: __views_path + 'layout.ejs',
    site: config.global.site,
    userOptions: req.session.userOptions
})
```

})

I am using node.js version 10.4.1, 64bit, together with Express.js using ejs view engine, and the entire application was built into binary using “pkg” version 4.3.8.

Any clue to help me out?